# Open specific link in Safari from UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, safari, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` which loads a local index.html file.

However I have an external link in this html file that I'd like to open in Safari instead of internally in the `UIWebView`.

Opening a link in safari from say a `UIButton` was simple enough:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"))
```

Opening the Instagram app from a external link also works like a charm.

```
<a href="instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882">instagram://media?id=434784289393782000_15903882</a>
```

So my first though was to do something like this:

```
<a href="safari://stackoverflow.com">Open in Safari</a>
```

However that doesn't seem to work, then I read something about using `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

But everyone who's managed to open an external link in Safari is writing in Obj-C which I'm not too familiar with as I'm writing in Swift.

Update with Swift Code:

```
import UIKit

class AccessoriesViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView:UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("accessories", withExtension: "html") {
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        }



    }
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if let url = request.URL where navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it!

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if let url = request.URL where navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Hmm something still seems to be wrong. I've added my swift code including your function. Would you be so kind to have a look at what's wrong? Truly appreciated!

Comment: have you given, `UIWebView` delegate?